# Raw pointer vs smart-pointer in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm trying to understand how can I substitute raw pointers on my C++ software with smart-pointers.

I have the following code:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<Bar *> m_member;
};
```

Now in some function I populate that vector with:

```
m_member.push_back( new Bar() );
```

and when my program finishes I delete the memory with:

```
for( std::vector<Bar *>::iterator it = m_member.begin(); it < m_member.end(); ++it )
{
    delete (*it);
    (*it) = NULL;
}
```

Now all this is good.

The problem is as I see it comes from the fact that at one point of time I may need to delete one of the member from the vector (this member is user-specified).

Now this is easy:

```
for(...)
{
    if( (*it)->GetFieldFromBar() == <user_specified_condition> )
    {
        delete (*it);
        (*it) = NULL;
    }
}
```

But how do I re-write it with the smart pointers? Is it even possible?

Comment: What have you tried?  It should be pretty easy to change `std::vector<Bar *> m_member;` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> m_member;`.  Then if you need to delete an element you just `erase` it.

Comment: (I would actually use unique_ptr and not shared_ptr in this case).

Comment: Why pointers at all, would `std::vector<Bar >` not suffice?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually far easier with smart pointers, and here `unique_ptr`.

Population is done through:

```
m_member.push_back(std::make_unique<Bar>()); // C++14, you can use std::unique_ptr<Bar>(new Bar) is you only have C++11
```

No need for a destructor.

For custom deletion:

```
for(auto& p: m_member)
{
    if( p->GetFieldFromBar() == <user_specified_condition> )
    {
        p.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to point out, std::make_unique is a c++14 function.

Comment: @AdamBrinded Very good point. I thought about it and forgot to add it.

Comment: It’s worth checking however, if your compiler(s) for a particular project support make_unique in c++11. If it does then make_unique is probably preferable.

Comment: And custom deletion might use erase-remove idiom now :)

Comment: @Jarod42 Depends, OP doesn't seem to want to remove the entry itself. At least not in what he showed us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>` is ideal in this case. You clearly have ownership in the vector.

Adding elements to it can be done the following in c++14:

```
m_member.push_back( std::make_unique<Bar>() );
```

Removing all elements gets reduced to: `m_member.clear()`   or even just letting it go out of scope.

Selectively removing the elements is better done like:

```
m_member.erase(std::remove_if(m_member.begin(), m_member.end(), [&](auto &&ptr) { return ptr->GetFieldFromBar() == <user_specified_condition>; }), m_member.end());
```

A bit descriptive for dealing with all elements, though, you can wrap it in a function to get rid of the boiler plate.

Comment: the question is marked with `c++11`, not `c++14`. Does this mean that the constructor will be `m_member.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Bar>( new Bar() ) )`?

Comment: Or emplace_back(new Bar()); unless you use libraries like absail or your STL exposes this also in c++11 mode